# Translating enumerated data in SQL / mapped status codes

Tags: mysql, sql

I wasn't entirely sure how to title this question, it's hard to describe what I mean in a title.  Basically what I have is enumerated status codes, and I'm looking for a simple way to map these to data within a query.

For example, let's say I have the following defined somewhere.  They are out of my control and are not in the database:

```
CODE     STATUS
----------------
1      = ACTIVE
2      = SUSPENDED
3      = CLOSED
4      = CANCELED
5      = ETC...
```

`SELECT item_title, status_code FROM mytable WHERE foo='bar';`

The integer code is stored in the database, but there are often cases where it would be helpful if I could make mysql aware of what they translate to, particularly for sorting but there have been many other times it would have been helpful.  I know it is possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT item_title,
    IF(status_code=1,'ACTIVE',
        IF(status_code=2,'SUSPENDED',
            IF(status_code=3,'CLOSED',
                IF(status_code=3,'CANCELED', ...)
            )
        )
    ) AS real_status
FROM mytable WHERE foo='bar';
```

But this is tedious, ugly, and error prone, and in some cases I may have 50 or more codes so this generally isn't a solution.  Ideally I would have the code definitions in a table so I could simply join it, but that is not an option.

I'm hoping there's some MySQL function or technique that I'm not aware of that will solve this.

Edit:
To clarify, the status codes are not defined in the database, they are defined in code.  I can translate the statuses in code after the query, but that is not ideal.  Essentially, I'm asking if there is a way to do this in sql:

`SELECT $statushash[tbl.status_code] AS real_status FROM mytable AS tbl...`

Comment: When you say making a table is impossible do you mean making any object, i.e. function, user-defined variable ( array in this case )?

Comment: No, I mean that moving the status definitions to a table is not possible.

Comment: Perhaps a temporary table would work, not sure about the performance tradeoff but this is mostly backend stuff so performance isn't really an issue...

Comment: In that case @Mark has just answered your question below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't create a lookup table, I can think of two possibilities:

1.Create a [user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html). However, the [restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html) on creating UDFs in MySQL are quite strict.

2.Create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that simulates a lookup table - something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_enum_lookup AS
select 1 as status_code, 'ACTIVE' as status_description UNION ALL
select 2 as status_code, 'SUSPENDED' as status_description UNION ALL
...
```

(etc.)